# Remove empty space on the Ubuntu 14.04 launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I was adding apps to the launcher when 3 slots appeared. When I hovered over them the message came up as "Drop to add application". I tried to drop and app into the slots but it just goes above them. Please help.
[image: Main screen]

[image: Small picture]

Comment: I don't think you can drop apps in that area

Comment: It's a common glitch in Unity that such tooltips keep sticking sometimes. You can normally make them disappear most easily by triggering them to appear again. - and +1 for the TARDIS :D Where do you have that wallpaper from?

Comment: I made it using gimp image editor. If you can find a way of me getting it to you then you can use it! And what do you mean by "triggering them to appear again"?

Comment: I fixed it! see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the launcher, alt+f2, typed 'unity', and pressed enter.
Log in and all should be normal.